# Gnuplot: Bar chart from a function

Tags: gnuplot, bar-chart

In difference to nearly 99.9% of all Gnuplot bar chart examples I don't have a data file but a function I want to visualize as a bar chart.

Let us take for example take the simple function f(x) = x

I want a bar char that creates one bar for every value of x between 0 and 20 (step size 1).

Therefore I used the following code, but it does not create 20 bars - it creates a lot more (about 100?).

```
set xtic 1
set xrange [0:20]
set boxwidth 1
set style fill solid
f(x)=x
plot f(x) with boxes
```

How to make this bar chart work correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `set samples` command.  Try:

```
set xtic 1
set xrange [0:20]
set boxwidth 1
set style fill solid
f(x)=x
set samples 21
plot f(x) with boxes
```